# Version Magic error while inserting a device driver

Tags: linux-device-driver, embedded-linux

I am modifying a device driver to check out for some bug and when i compile and try  to insert in my board all it says is ath_hal: version magic '2.6.31--LSDK-9.2.0_U10.5.13**-svn311** mod_unload MIPS32_R2 32BIT ' should be '2.6.31--LSDK-9.2.0_U10.5.13 mod_unload MIPS32_R2 32BIT '.The question thus is how to change the default magic version for my module.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was a bit more complex as it is i had to edit the Kernel makefile and search for the source of the string being added.I have found out that the "localver-full" variable was being filled with the desired string and so things were to be fixed there.I simply filled that variable with NULL.